# Unable to move textview iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextview

I am trying to change the co-ordinates of the text view during runtime. But the view is not moving. I have used same code for Iphone and it works fine there.

```
//_actionTakenTextViewIpad is the UITextView.

    if(count<=3)
    {
        _actionTakenTextViewIpad.frame=CGRectMake(60, 385, 589, 103);     
    }

    else if (count<=6)
    {
        _actionTakenTextViewIpad.frame=CGRectMake(60, 485, 589, 103);
    }

    else
    {
        _actionTakenTextViewIpad.frame=CGRectMake(60, 585, 589, 103);
    }
```

It looks very simple but what am i missing here?
PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this on main thread ??

Comment: i have kept a breakpoint and its hitting.. Placed it in viewWillAppear

Comment: try [_actionTakenTextViewIpad setNeedsDisplay] after updating frame

Comment: tried that but no luck.. FYI, i have wrapped it inside a Scroll view . is that the problem?

Comment: can you check _actionTakenTextViewIpad is not nil when calling the method? I do not see any other reason why it would not work. Or frame is changed somewhere else in the code.

Comment: better you attach some screenshot / paste some code related to scrollview

Comment: slecome.. Nil means no text? currently the textview doesnt have any text entry. How will it be a problem as I am new ,no idea? and the frame is not set anywhere..

Comment: guys..i don't have enough point to attach screen shot.. I noticed that the view is not moving but when i click to edit inside it , the cursor blinks at middle of view(i mean the position which is mentioned in co-ordinates for text view.)

Comment: If you are using AUTOLAYOUT then you wont be able to change the frame. You need to create constrain and set values for those respective constrains in order to change the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AUTOLAYOUT then you wont be able to change the frame. You need to create constrain and set values for those respective constrains in order to change the frame.